# Fire UIPanGestureRecognizer with an outside starting point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a layout like the image below:

[image: question image]

The black area is a camera, the red area is just an UIView with a UIPanGestureRecognizer and the green area a UICollectionView with images.

Right now, if the user presses the red area and starts dragging all the layout is moved to top and the user is able to see more items in the collection view at once while the camera overflows the device screen. All the logic is already done.

My problem is that I want the same functionality even if the user starts dragging outside of the red area, i.e. the user starts dragging  the collection view from the bottom of the device so more items are shown, but if the user reaches (crosses, moves over) the red area, then the PanGestureRecognizer should get fired. Instagram has this functionality when selecting an image from disk. Is there a way to achieve this that I am missing? I tried overriding the red view with pointInside, touchesBegan and  touchesMoved, but any of those get called if the drag comes from the collection view. SwipeGesture doesn't work either. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

1) Add your PanGesture (the red one) that you want activated to the collection view too:

```
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:redPanGesture];
```

2) In the method that gets called when the PanGesture is activated, filter it so that the logic gets executed only when the finger is on top of the red area:

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.redView];

if(location.y > self.redView.frame.size.height)
{
    [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    return;
}
```

3) Set your class as the PanGesture's delegate:

```
redPanGesture.delegate = self;
```

4) Implement the method below, otherwise the collection view will not scroll:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm